# Boot up problem with RHEL 6

Tags: linux, rhel

I restarted my RHEL 6 box and now I can't get past the logo screen. I tried booting without the splash screen so I could see what's going on, and I'm getting an error message saying something along the lines of:

> make * * * /lib/modules/[kernel]/build No such file or directory. Stop.
>   make * * * [all] Error 2

Then it starts a few other things without any problems (sshd, ntpd, ..., up to Windows binary loader), but then it hangs up after that. To me it appears that the modules folder might be missing (or incorrect), but I'm not sure if that's what's causing it from not booting at all. Would I be able to use a Live CD and fix this somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the installation finished successfully? You receive that error when the kernel headers aren't available. If it's possible to LiveCD in to the machine, I believe you can chroot the filesystem of RHEL and then yum update. That *may* fix it.